# How to access the user's facebook public information in firebase?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication, facebook-login

I have requested and got approved `public_profile` and `email` for my app.

Upon clicking the `login with Facebook` button I’m requesting these two permissions:

```
let fbLoginManager = FBSDKLoginManager()
fbLoginManager.logIn(withReadPermissions: ["public_profile", "email"], from: self) { (result, error) in
```

After the successful login flow, I get to the part where the user has authenticated. (Maybe I’m doing this too late, but not sure where else I should try to access the profile information?)

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        FIRAuth.auth()!.addStateDidChangeListener() { auth, user in
            if let user = user {
                FIRDatastore.shared.setUser(user: User(authData: user))
                self.performSegue(withIdentifier: self.loginToList, sender: nil)
            }
        }
    }
```

The `user` object, in this case, is of type FIRUser class.  This should contain the public profile information.  However, I see only a subset of the information under authData.providerData[0]

> providerID, userID, displayName, photoURL and email.

I don’t see gender or anything else from the public_profile as explained [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions/#reference-public_profile).

What am I missing, please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/auth/FirebaseUser) these are the only user properties you can access:

[image]

Which is similar to the [User object](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.User) properties:

[image]

I'm guessing that Facebook authentication is just for email and password verification only.

Comment: This is really odd, there is no way to achieve that in a different approach? How do create a profile after all without this information?

Comment: As far as I know, you are just using Facebook as authentication of the user's email. If you have a login based on password-based account the user has to verify their email. Facebook is a trusted authentication of the user's email. You are not creating a "Facebook" user within Firebase.

Comment: Sorry, I think I didn't explain it properly. I have created facebook login for web applications before, and upon signing up the first time, I was able to fetch the public information of the user and store as a base profile within the web app.  If I wanted to achieve that here, ideally I should obtain this information right after signup when the user has given the permissions for firebase authentification. You mean that this can't be done with Firebase auth, but can I do that separately via facebook libs without asking for permissions again? Thanks

Comment: As far as I know, *here* you are just using Facebook for Firebase authentication. After authentication your app has access to the properties shown in my answer. I haven't used Facebook libs for while but I *think* you would have to ask for permissions again because you require access to Facebook user properties *not* Firebase user properties.